# One-to-many relationships in drift(moor)

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, flutter-moor

I have two tables: students and groups. I need to implement a one-to-many relationship of these tables so that when I create a student I have a list of groups from the database and I can add the student to a specific group. And so that when I click on a group, I have a list of students who are part of it. How can i do this?
Group table and group model:

```js
class GroupDB extends Table {
  IntColumn get id => integer().autoIncrement().nullable()();
  TextColumn get groupName => text().named('group_name')();
}

class Group {
  Group({
    this.id,
    required this.groupName,
  });
  int? id;
  String groupName;
}
```

Student table and model:

```js
class StudentsDB extends TableWithIntId {
IntColumn get id => integer().autoIncrement().nullable()();
  TextColumn get firstName => text().named('first_name')();
  TextColumn get lastName => text().named('last_name')();
}

class Student {
  Student({
    this.id,
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
  });
  int? id;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
}
```